# How to calculate the expected cost?

Tags: math, statistics, probability

I am not good at probability and I know it's not a coding problem `directly`. But I wish you would help me with this. While I was solving a computation problem I found this difficulty:

**Problem definition:**

> The Little Elephant from the Zoo of Lviv is going to the Birthday
>   Party of the Big Hippo tomorrow. Now he wants to prepare a gift for
>   the Big Hippo. He has N balloons, numbered from 1 to N. The i-th
>   balloon has the color Ci and it costs Pi dollars. The gift for the Big
>   Hippo will be any subset (chosen randomly, possibly empty) of the
>   balloons such that the number of different colors in that subset is at
>   least M. Help Little Elephant to find the expected cost of the gift.

**Input**

> The first line of the input contains a single integer T - the number
>   of test cases. T test cases follow. The first line of each test case
>   contains a pair of integers N and M. The next N lines contain N pairs
>   of integers Ci and Pi, one pair per line.

**Output**

**In T lines print T real numbers - the answers for the corresponding test cases. Your answer will considered correct if it has at most 10^-6 absolute or relative error.**

**Example**

**Input:**

> 2
>
> 2 2
>
> 1 4
>
> 2 7
>
> 2 1
>
> 1 4
>
> 2 7

**Output:**

> 11.000000000
>
> 7.333333333

So, Here I don't understand why the expected cost of the gift for the second case is 7.333333333, because the expected cost equals `Summation[xP(x)]` and according to this formula it should be 33/2?

Yes, it is a codechef question. But, I am not asking for the solution or the algorithm( because if I take the algo from other than it would not increase my coding potentiality). I just don't understand their example. And hence, I am not being able to start thinking about the algo.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about probability, not programming, and belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possible choices, 1, 2, 1+2, with costs 4, 7 and 11. Each is equally likely, so the expected cost is (4 + 7 + 11) / 3 = 22 / 3 = 7.33333.